# How to add interpolation properly on a print component in Angular 2?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, data-binding, interpolation

When including the *ngFor on my template the invoice gets blank on print.
Also, the interpolation did not work on it.I am getting data from an another component.When i debug the data is receiving properly.I initialized another property in the constructor called name and it got working.

```
constructor (){
this.printData = {};
this.printData.name = 'User';
}
```

But i am unable to show data from other sources.Is this any problem related to innerHtml or something?

#### invoice.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-invoice',
  templateUrl: './invoice.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./invoice.component.css']
})
export class InvoiceComponent  {
  printData:any;
  constructor() {
    this.printData = {};
  }
  print(data:any): void {         //Getting data from another component.
    console.log('Print Invoice');
    if(data) {
      let stringified = JSON.stringify(data);
      this.printData = JSON.parse(stringified);
      console.log('Data loaded to print');
  }
      this.startPrint('printSectionId');

}
  startPrint(printSectionId: string){
          let popupWinindow;
          let innerContents = document.getElementById(printSectionId).innerHTML;
          popupWinindow = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=600,height=700,scrollbars=no,menubar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,titlebar=no');
          popupWinindow.document.open();
          popupWinindow.document.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" /></head><body onload="window.print()">' + innerContents + '</html>');
          popupWinindow.document.close();
    }

}
```

#### invoice.component.html

```
  <div id="printSectionId" >
      <div  *ngFor="let item of printData.items"  >

  <pre style="line-height:0.5; text-align: justify;  text-justify: inter-word;">
      <div style="text-align: center"><b><h3>Company Name</h3></b></div >
      <div style="text-align: center">Caption</div >
      <div style="text-align: center">Address</div >

      <hr>
      <div style="text-align: center"><b>Invoice</b></div >
      <br>
      Serial No: {{printData.serialNo}}         Date:{{printData.date}}

      Item name: {{item.name}}
      Quantity: {{item.quantity}}

  </pre>
     </div>

  </div>
```